# Are there triangulations of the sphere (see below) for which every vertex four-coloring consists of a single Kempe chain for each color-pair?

Tags: graph-theory

In other words, if 1, 2, 3, and 4 represent the four colors available and i and j are colors with i < j, then each proper coloring of the triangulation of the sphere using all four colors has one and only one (i,j) Kempe chain--that is, one and only one Kempe chain for each of the six color-pairs.

I am interested only in triangulations meeting two additional conditions:

1. The degree of every vertex in the triangulation must be at least four.
2. There can be no separating triangle in the graph (a triangle with vertices of the graph both inside and outside the triangle).

The icosahedron with triangular faces for which every vertex has degree 5 exhibits the desired coloring property. The question is whether there are any other examples, and if so, how many?

Comment: $K_4$ is another one.

Comment: Indeed.  Thank you.  Are there others of higher order?

Answer (score 0):

```
Starting with $K_4$ you can construct an infinite family.
```

Write down the 6 Kempe chains as
12,13,14,23,24,34.

Note that only 3 vertices occur at the end of the chains.
Add a vertex in the center of these 3 vertices and connect it to each of them
(triangle 234 in this case).
Your new Kempe chains are 121,131,141,23,24,34.

This repeats indefinitely.

At each step the last vertex you added occurs at the end of three Kempe chains, and you find only 3 vertices forming a triangle at the ends. Choose these three for the next step.

You can try to make a nice induction argument if you like.

Comment: Thank you again. Your (correct) answers keep forcing me to refine the question usefully.  I should say that I am interested in discovering triangulations that have no "separating triangles."That is, no triangle having vertices both inside and outside the triangle.  So K4 works as an answer, but the infinite chain of successive triangles does not.  And I am interested only in graphs of order greater than four.  It seems that, with your help, I am getting closer to the precise question I intended to ask.  I am still wondering whether the icosahedron with triangular faces is the only answer.

Comment: Not everybody that is interested will read all answers and comments. Please edit your question to make clear that you are only looking for irreducible configurations.